# Problem reading python code

Tags: python, json

Can someone explain the following python code.

```
value_geojson["features"][0]["properties"]["title"]
```

value_geojson is a geojson variable.
I like to think that I'm not a total python newbie but these are too many [] for me. I am a GeoJSON newbie though.

Would appreciate help on that one, eventhough I know it's probably to simple for SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See sections [3.2 and 3.3 of the geojson standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2).

It looks like `value_geojson` is a `FeatureCollection` object, which have a single member `"features"` which is a list of `Feature` objects.  So

```py
value_geojson["features"][0]
```

is now just the first `Feature` object.  Those have a few members, including `"properties"`, which is an arbitrary JSON object.  At that point we're outside of the geojson standard, so whatever `"title"` means is more context-specific.

Comment: ok that already helped me a bit.

So, "value_geojson["features"][0]" returns the first Object in value_geojson.
Each Object is basically a python dictionary with the keys "properties" and "title". 

Thus, the full line returns the values of both keys for the first Object? 

In the tutorial I saw that line it returns "5000.00 ". Thus, "5000.00" is the value stored in "Properties" and " " is the value stored in "title"?

Comment: No, those last two are also nested.  `...["properties"]` is itself a dictionary, probably with many key-value pairs, one of which is evidently (very strangely) `"title": "5000.00"`.  Try printing `value_geojson["features"][0]["properties"].keys()`.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks a lot :). 

When I run your line I get: 
dict_keys(['fill', 'fill-opacity', 'stroke', 'stroke-opacity', 'stroke-width', 'title']). Thus, yes title has apparently the value "5000.00".